# Displaying a boolean as a Yes/No within a Webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I am trying to use a **Webgrid** and I can get the data to display but the **bool values** are where I'm having problems. I would like to just display *Yes or No instead of true or false*.

```
 webGridColumns.Add(new WebGridColumn 
{ ColumnName = "IsActive", CanSort = true, Header = "Is Active" });
```

Whats the right way to do this. Please give some idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself after doing some search.

If anybody faces this problem, I hope it will help them.

```
webGridColumns.Add(new WebGridColumn { 
    ColumnName = "IsActive",
    Header = "Is Active",
    CanSort = true,
    Format= @<text>
        @(item.IsActive ? "Yes" : "No" )
    </text>}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to change it slightly for dotnet framework

```
  grid. Column("Suspended",
        format: @<text>@(item.Suspended == true ?Suspended" : " ")</text>),
```